# I2C only listener without connecting into network

Tags: arduino, i2c

I'm having Arduino as board computer in my car... but i want to hook up to LPG communication between (LPG)ECU and (LPG) switch. Communication between switch and ecu is I2C (switch is in slave mode).

I read documentation for all possible communications between these two microchips and my guess  is  I2C is most likely.

Soo ...I want to detect fuel switching and fuel level of LPG instalation.

Is it possuble to listen communication without disturbing and etc...?

How can i use Wire (or other) class to read communication data or need to build my own ?

(Sorry for my english )

Comment: The I2C sounds unlikely for noisy environments. It's more likely SMBus.

Comment: And in any case the "usual" hardware I2C is not useful in this case, since it will reply to requests and control the clock instead of the switch. IF it is really a I2C, you can try to look at the [Software I2C Library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SoftwareI2CLibrary) to see how to implement I2C in software and then edit it to become a I2C sniffer (it does not have to write anything on the bus). Or, an easier way, you can attach a (digital) oscilloscope, see the signal being transmitted, then train the arduino to detect THAT particular command only